# Python processing a range of numbered (dated) files in a directory

Tags: python, file-io, glob, python-2.x

I am trying to find a range of specific files in a directory using python 2.7.
I have many files in a directory that are named like AB_yyyyjjjhhmmss_001.txt, where y is year, j is julian date, h is hour and so on. Each time corresponds to the time some data was taken and not necessarily the time the file was created or manipulated. I like to pick out a range of time, say from 2013305010000 to 2013306123000 and process them.

I have something like,

```
import glob

def get_time (start_time = None, end_time = None):

    if start_time == None:
        start_time = input("start: ")
    if end_time == None:
        end_time = input("end: ")

    duration = str(start_time) + "-" + str(end_time)

    listing = glob.glob("*_[" + duration + "]_*")
```

I learned that `[ ]` are only meant to match single digit. So I am totally off track here. I also tried `{start_time..end_time}` combo with no avail.

Answer (score 5):

If all files have the same structure, you can simply write:

```
import os
import re
start = sys.argv[1]
end = sys.argv[2]
for filename in os.listdir('test'):
    if start <= filename.split('_')[1] <= end:
        print "Process %s" % filename
```

Example:

```
$ ls test
AB_2013105010000_001.txt AB_2013305010000_001.txt AB_2013306103000_001.txt 
AB_2013306123000_001.txt AB_2013316103000_001.txt

$ python t.py 2013305010000 2013306123000
Process AB_2013305010000_001.txt
Process AB_2013306103000_001.txt
Process AB_2013306123000_001.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, damien. This is very cool. Indeed the files names are all in same structure. split will definitely be useful. I find it fascinating that arithmetic like start <= filename.split('_')[1] <= end works for a string. I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I might try

```
import re
import os
import datetime

def filename_to_datetime(filename):
    filedate = re.match(r'.*(\d{13}).*', filename)
    if filedate:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(re.match(filedate.group(1), '%Y%j%H%M%S')
    else:
        raise ValueError("File has wrong format!")

def get_time(start_time, end_time):
    return [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if
            start_time < filename_to_datetime(filename) < end_time]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! You posted this answer within 10 min of my post! Amazing!! I will definitely try re and datetime. That seems very useful.